# Microchip webserver, don't receive ack after HTTP 200 OK frame

Tags: c, sockets, http, tcp, microcontroller

My current project is a bare-metal webserver. For this I'm using no libraries, and programming directly onto the chip. What I'm trying to do right now is send a single piece of HTTP data:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Content-Length: 45\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
Server: microserver\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
\r\n
<!DOCTYPE html><html>Hello<br>world!<hr></html>
```

My server tries to go through the following steps:

1. Receive SYN
2. Send [SYN+ACK]
3. Receive ACK
4. Receive ACK containing HTTP GET
5. Send [ACK,PUSH,FIN] with HTTP data (this one changed a lot, I've tried sending ACK PUSH and FIN seperately (with the content in PUSH), tried [ACK+PUSH],FIN and ACK,[PUSH+FIN] as well.
6. Receive [ACK+FIN] <<--- Here's where it goes wrong, this one is never even sent, according to wireshark.
7. Send ACK.

As said, it goes wrong at step 6. every single time. No matter what combination of ACK, PUSH and FIN I use in step 5. When looking at it with wireshark all the SEQ and ACK numbers are correct.

My server is able to close connections once the [FIN+ACK] finally does get sent, which sometimes happens on sockets that are kept open by the browser synchronously.

Pcap file of what wireshark records: https://www.dropbox.com/s/062k9hkgkenaqij/httpdump.pcap with as filter: `(tcp.dstport == 80 || tcp.srcport == 80) && (ip.dst == 169.254.100.100 || ip.src == 169.254.100.100)`

I know there is a 4 year old very similar question, [Building a webserver, client doesn't acknowledge HTTP 200 OK frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592068/building-a-webserver-client-doesnt-acknowledge-http-200-ok-frame), but I've tried pretty much everything that was suggested in there, and it didn't seem to get me any further, so I'm out of ideas.

EDIT:
I have found the problem, after studying sections of wireshark captures for hours an end. Apparently the mistake was that I did not use data to calculate the TCP checksum... But well, found the solution.

Comment: What TCP stack are you using?

Comment: I'm using HTTP, TCP, IPv4, Ethernet II

Comment: Post your edit as an answer instead; we prefer not to have questions hanging around without answers...

Comment: Unfortunately, due to someone downvoting me in a previous question because I said that tcp was under ethernet instead of on top (which I later edited), I am currently under an answer ban. So, as much as I'd like to, I can not post an answer to my own question.